# Less than operator cannot be overloaded as member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I want to use my `class` as `key` in a `map`, so I overload `operator+`. It works well if I overload it as a friend function. When I overload it as a member function inside the class, it causes a compile error.

> *error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Syl' (or there is no acceptable conversion)'*.

In details, this doesn't compile, and generate the compile error:

Syl.h

```
bool operator< (const Syl& rhs);
```

Syl.cpp

```
bool Syl::operator< (const Syl& rhs) {  return false; }
```

While this compiles.

Syl.h

```
friend bool operator< (const Syl& lhs, const Syl& rhs);
```

Syl.cpp

```
bool operator< (const Syl& lhs, const Syl& rhs) {   return false; }
```

I don't know why. I know that operator< is binary, but is there anyway to overload it as function member?

Comment: Due to the way overload resolution and implicit conversions work, the `friend` version is a better idea anyway.

Comment: The friendly version specifies, both operands as `const` the other version only says that the input parameter is `const`. You must mark the method as such... You have to read the error carefully, pay an extra attention to the meaning of words such as `const`, `signed`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, member operators such as `operator<` do not modify the object they operate on. If that is the case you need to specify that the method is constant by putting the keyword `const` at the end of the declaration, i.e.

```
class Syl {
  ...
  public:
  bool operator<(const Syl& rhs) const;  
}
```

An operator like that can be used with STL containers such as `std::map`.

---

Your current version of the member operator, when translated into a stand-alone operator would look as:

```
friend bool operator<(Syl& lhs, const Syl& rhs);
```

Notice the lack of `const` for `lhs`. It is still correct per se, but atypical. You need to provide an l-value as `lhs`. If you provide something else you get the *``no operator found...''* error. STL `std::map` does not expect that either, hence your error, probably originating from standard headers, somewhere deep in the template implementation.

Comment: So the compile time error does not come from the way he declared the overloaded operator, it comes from the fact that the member overloaded operator is used to order a map which will only accept overloaded `<` operator if both of its arguments are const ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: That is correct - operators are not required to be `const`. Some typically are not (e.g. `operator=`), some usually are. Note however that non-const operators require an `lvalue` as the left argument and you will get a similar error if you don't provide one.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` and `b` are both of type `Syl`, your first (member form) is not valid in an expression `a < b` if `a` is `const`, and will result in a compilation error.

To fix that, you need to specify the member `operator<()` as

```
bool operator< (const Syl& rhs) const;    // note the trailing const
```

Without that trailing `const`, in an expression `a < b`, `a` cannot be `const`  (i.e. the `operator<()` is permitted to change it).

Your second form is correct, since it specifies that both operands are `const` references.

Comparison operators like `<` don't generally change EITHER of their operands.  The `const` qualifiers communicate that fact.

Bear in mind that you can provide the member form OR the non-member form.   Providing both will cause an error due to ambiguity (the compiler has no basis to prefer one over the other, when it sees an expression like `a < b`).